# How to use LLDB from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, lldb

Normally I'm using LLDB from Xcode, but for some cases I would prefer using Terminal.
I tried to type in "xcrun lldb" , and then I set lldb mode, but how do I set the right target?

Comment: Did you check the Apple docs? The very first section shows how to specify the program to debug:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-terminal-workflow-tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012917-CH4-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Apple docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-terminal-workflow-tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012917-CH4-SW1)

Specifying the Program to Debug

First, you need to set the program to debug. As with GDB, you can start LLDB and specify the file you want to debug using the command line. Type:

$ lldb /Projects/Sketch/build/Debug/Sketch.app
Current executable set to '/Projects/Sketch/build/Debug/Sketch.app' (x86_64).
Or you can specify the executable file to debug after it is already running using the file command:

$ lldb
(lldb) file /Projects/Sketch/build/Debug/Sketch.app
Current executable set to '/Projects/Sketch/build/Debug/Sketch.app' (x86_64).

A simple Google finds this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and yes i did look at this documentary, but the thing is, i do not understand what is this ".app" mean? When i use ".xcodeproj"  i get "is a directory" message... What i'm i doing wrong?

Comment: ".app' is the file name extension. It is usually hidden but there is a option in the Finder Preferences:Advanced "Show all filename extensions", check that option and you will see the filename extensions. Why are you using ".xcodeproj"? You need to use the complete path to the application. You will need to find the app in the file system.

Comment: As an example for a project of mine the Derived Data is at: "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comics-dihbvzzymyqdhndidgvkglfprqbb". The app is inside that directory at "Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Comics.app". The full path is: "/Users/dan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Comics-dihbvzzymyqdhndidgvkglfprqbb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Comics.app" You need to specify the full path to the actual app.

Comment: Mainly this method of use of LLDB is limited to OSX apps. I'm not sure how to run an iOS app directly in LLDB since they run in a Simulator.

Answer (score 3):

**iOS Simulator**

```
$ lldb
> process attach -n "AppName" -w
```

Then start app in iOS Simulator ([ioslib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioslib) can do this from command line). LLDB will connect once it discovers the app process.

**iOS Device**

Use [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy) (`ios-deploy -d -W -b path/to/foo.app`). It will launch and connect an LLDB session.

**OSX App**

`process attach -n "AppName"` in LLDB might work (not verified).